# How can I use CUDA without the monitor?

Tags: cuda

I'm using a lot of desktops for image processing.

I usually access each desktops with remote controls in my Home's network.

So I only have one monitor.

However, one problem was occurred.

I tried to use CUDA with all of my desktops for parallel processing, but it was failed.

When I execute sample program likes 'deviceQuery',
I could see the error message, 'no cuda capable device is detected'.

I assume if desktop is disconnected to monitor, then it prints out such as above message.

How can I use CUDA without the monitor?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How are you connecting to the machines, are you using Microsoft Remote Desktop protocol ?

Comment: I'm sorry about late reply. I'm using Win7 SP1 / Enterprise and Windows' remote control feature from Start menu.

Comment: I think this is probably using RDP.  When you use RDP to connect from one windows machine to another, you cannot access the GPUs in the target machine, if those GPUs are using WDDM driver model.  So the first thing would be to switch to another connection mechanism like VNC or teamviewer or similar.

Comment: Since my computer can't find GPU device without monitor, I connected another monitor to sub-PC. That is working.

Comment: The situation is not really clear.  Are you saying that if you connect a monitor, then if you access that PC remotely, you can use the GPUs?  If so, then the issue is probably a function of your system BIOS behavior amongst multiple GPUs when no monitor is attached.  A lot more information would probably be needed to sort it out.  But it should be possible to use the GPUs in a PC even if no monitor is attached.

Comment: I just read your comment. In other words, if I use VNC or teamviewer instead of RDP, I will be able to use CUDA in sub-PC. Is that right? (I'm sorry, I can English a little).

Comment: Yes, if you connect a monitor, then you should be able to use the PC and GPUs by working locally on that PC.  But if you want to access it remotely, you cannot use RDP with WDDM GPUs (with or without a monitor).  If you use some other access method, like VNC or teamviewer, you should be able to remotely access the PC and use the GPU, with or without a monitor on the remote PC.

Comment: Oh, as you said, I want to access sub-PC remotely. And I used RDP. Umm.. anyway, can I solve this problem with any setting of BIOS, using RDP?

Comment: No.  You need to use another access method.

Comment: I'm sorry about late reply. I did successfully use cuda without monitor, thanks to you. Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: I would suggest you add an answer to your own question (yes, you can do that) to explain what changes you had to make to get it working.  It may be useful for others.

Comment: OK, I will do it. However, is that correct that I answer to my question by myself?

Comment: Yes, it's OK.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did successfully use cuda without monitor!

This solution is given by Robert Crovella.

First of all, the cause of the problem is RDP.

If I use the Remote Desktop Protocols provided by Windows 7,

then I can't access the GPUs.

This is because GPUs are using WDDM driver model.

That's why, I connected to my sub-PC using another program,

and I did successfully access the GPUs !

For example, available program is VNC, teamviewer, and etc.

I used the TightVNC.

That's all.

Thanks again for your help, Rovert Crovella.